# Nontrivial subspace of $ \mathbb{{R}^2}$

Tags: vector-spaces

If $F$ is a non-trivial subspace of $ \mathbb{{R}^2}$,and the vector $v\in F-\left\{   \vec{0} \right\} $ then F= $\left\{  \alpha v;\alpha\in\mathbb{R} \right\} $  .it's easy to show (by the defintion of a subspace )that  $\left\{  \alpha v;\alpha\in\mathbb{R} \right\} $ $\subset $  $F$,but I can't prove the inverse inclusion.
Can someone please give me a rigorous proof?  Is there another way of proving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \in F \setminus \{0\}$. We want to show that $F \subset \{\alpha v \colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Assume for a contradiction, there is a $u$ in $F$ not of the form $\alpha v$.

**Claim:** $u,v$ are independent.

Suppose $b u + a v = 0$. We need to show $a=b=0$. If $b=0$, then $a=0$ as $v$ is a non-zero vector. So assume $b \neq 0$. Then since $-bu = av$, we have $u= (-a/b)v$ contradicting our assumption. Thus, $u,v$ are independent.

Thus, $F$ contains two independent vectors and is hence equal to $\mathbb{R}^2$, a contradiction to the assumption it was a non-trivial subspace.

Comment: By definition $u,v$ are independent if $au +b v = 0$ implies $a=b=0$.

Comment: A set of independent elements in a space is a basis of the space if the number of elements is equal to the dimension of the space, and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $2$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But a non-trivial subspace is a subspace other than $\{0\}$ or the full space (so in this case $\mathbb{R}^2$). The contradiction is to $F \neq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: OKay I think I know what you mean. I did not start my proof with the part you gave anyway inmplictly. One should start with: "Let  $v \in F \setminus \{0\}$." That $F$ is non-zero is used when the $v$ is assumed to exist.

Comment: You cannot say that $F= \{0\}$ since this is excluded. You only consider nontrivial spaces. What was a justifed remark though is that we need to use this at some point and I now explained where this is used.

Comment: I added a phrase at the start of the answer, as explained in a comment above. If $F$ is zero, I cannot take a nonzeo $v$ in $F$ and there is really nothing to even start. This is were it is used.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad the information was useful.